# How to make "un-entered" user input show "not available" -- Java

Tags: java, user-input

I am just a beginner, so any help would be appreciated.

So here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccountScanner {

public static void main (String[] args) {

String name, course;
int age;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter name: ");
name = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter age: ");
age = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Course: ");
course = input.next();

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Name:" +name);
System.out.println("Age:" +age);
System.out.println("Course:" +course);


System.exit(0);
}
}
```

but what if the user did enter one of the details. What can I do to make it display "Not Available" instead

example:

```
enter name: Zack
enter age: 
enter course: BSCS
```

output would be:

```
Name: Zack
Age: Not available
Course: BSCS
```

Comment: Please format your code to include indentation

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `conditional operator` to check if the inputs are empty and show the result correspondingly as follows:

```
String name, course, age;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter name: ");
name = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter age: ");
age = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter Course: ");
course = input.nextLine();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Name:" +(name.isEmpty()?"Not Available":name));
System.out.println("Age:" +(age.isEmpty()?"Not Available":new Integer(age)));
System.out.println("Course:" +(course.isEmpty()?"Not Available":course));
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!  I tried it, but somehow I can only make the "name" empty , when I tried to hit enter in the "age" it wont go to "course" like it requires me to enter something to move forward. Same with course..

Comment: @PoorGamer answer updated. ``course`` is working fine though. But in order for ``age`` to be skippable, you can make it a ``String`` and then parse it to and ``Integer`` if it was set